# C#/WPF Desktop applications deployed in CI/CD azure devops to client desktop machine

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

We have a desktop application that we want to deploy to our clients machine(A lot of them, on premise as well as other offices). We are currently using CI to create the installer but it seems a  lot of work in installing the software to the client machines. Also, since the desktop application is new, we are expecting additional features and improvement.

Is it possible to perform Continuous deployment for desktop applications on client machines? Every time we push a new version, all the installed applications will also be updated.

Comment: There are multiple ways to approach this, mostly depending on how you expect clients to receive updates. Manually obtain the new software? Auto updates on startup (think chrome), something else? "CD" when you are talking about externally installed software is about making the software _avaliable_ for download, not forcefully installing on another person's computer.

Comment: One way to approach this is to build a custom loader. Rather than running the app the user runs a loader app. This checks whether there are newer versions of dll from some configurable source. That then runs your app. Usually the entry point exe is minimal and loads everything from dll. A variant omits the separate loader but again has a pretty small exe. That downloads new versions of everything tona folder in appdata in the background as the app runs. When you start up it checks if there was a newer version pulled down on the last run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a too complex task for Azure DevOps because you have to install and register deployment agents into each client machine and create a deployment flow. This task is more suitable for centralized software control solutions (like [EMCO Remote Installer](https://emcosoftware.com/remote-installer), [ManageEngine Desktop Central](https://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/), and others).

In this case:

1. Azure DevOps builds and publishes your applications in some shareable folder.
2. Each client place installs new versions with your centralized software control solution.

Comment: Management decided to just deploy the installer on a server folder. Users can get notified about the tool and they can access it to manually install it on their machine. Thank you. :)